Use of the article before a plural name
When I write in English I have frequently the following doubt.
The following sentence use the singular form:

Now the code executes the following instruction: ...

In the previous sentence I have inserted the article the before instruction because the name is singular.
But when the name is plural I have to use the article or not? So in the following sentence:

Now the code executes following instructions: instruction1, instruction2, and so on ...

OR

Now the code executes the following instructions: instruction1, instruction2, and so on ...

I have tried to read following posts:

Plurals with and without a definite article in a relative clause
In this post the sentence:


Each of the following sentences is preceded by a bare infinitive.

is closest to mine, but the presence of the word Each, on my opinion, could change something in the chosen of use of the article.
So I have not found a certain solution of my doubt.
With or without the?

Have another look at your first link.  The instructions which the code executes are specific ones, so the definite article is required - the following instructions.

Thanks. I have some difficult to understand the explanation of the link (may be  for my low English knowledge in general) but now I know that I have to add the article in sentences similar to the sentence shown by my question. Now I have to modified many posts on other Stackexchange sites :)

The noun’s number (singular or plural) has no effect on whether the definite article is required. The dependence on number applies only to the indefinite article, as in The farmer keeps a cow and The farmer keeps ducks.
